# Java com port read and write issue

Tags: java, serial-communication

Firstly let me introduce my program. My application pure java and use comm jar for com port. I already added

1. `win32com.dll` - `jre/bin`
2. `comm.jar` - `jre/lib/ext`
3. `java.comm.properties` - `jre/liv`

The following is my program

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.comm.SerialPort;

public class PortReaderWriter
{
    static Enumeration<?> ports;
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static InputStream inputStream;
    static OutputStream outputStream;
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static String messageString = "abc";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

            while (ports.hasMoreElements())
            {
                portId = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
                System.out.println("Port " + portId.getName());

                if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                {
                    if (portId.getName().equals("COM1"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("====================");
                        System.out.println("COM1 found");

                        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("PortReaderWriter", 2000);
                        serialPort
                                .setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                        outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
                        System.out.println(messageString.getBytes() + "  Successfully Sent!");

                        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
                        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2048];
                        while (inputStream.available() > 0)
                        {
                            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                            System.out.println("numBytes " + numBytes);
                        }
                        System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));

                        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                        outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());
                        System.out.println(messageString.getBytes() + "  Successfully Sent!");

                        System.out.println("====================");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Port COM3
Port COM1
====================
COM1 found
[B@1a52fdf  Successfully Sent!

====================
Port LPT1
Port LPT2
```

But My expected output is

```
COM1 found
[B@1a52fdf  Successfully Sent!
abc
====================
Port LPT1
Port LPT2
```

In the program, I am not sure "abc" is sent or not and in the output I can not see. Please help me is there any required to add or change. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `messageString.getBytes()` in the following statement returns a byte array instead of the string itself :

```
System.out.println(messageString.getBytes() + "  Successfully Sent!");
```

and that is why you get a `[B@1a52fdf` instead of the message itself.

Of course, when you send the data you send a byte array, but if you wish to see what was sent in a String form, you could use the below :

```
System.out.println(messageString + "  Successfully Sent!");
```

Additionally, the statement `System.out.println("Port " + portId.getName());` prints every Port name; if you only wish to show the port name for ports that have been found as per your criteria (as the `Port COM3` and `Port COM1` ar missing from your desired output), you could omit this statement.